# AWS ioT: user connection from a Thing (with restricted policy ?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iot

I'm trying to implement AWS IoT in my developments and I'm having troubble to design my authentication workflow.
Basically, I imagine a collection of users (via IAM) and a fleet of devices (via IoT). So far so good. But what if I want to allow users to authenticate via the devices they own ?
And especially:

- Can a user have two connection methods depending if the user connect from a desktop App (with a keyboard which allows strong password) or if the connection is done through the IoT device (with only a numeric keyboard, so weak password)
- For obvious security reason, if such connections are possible, I would like to implement different policies according to whether the user is atuthenticating through the App desktop or one of his devices...

Do you have any clue ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question, and I'll try answering by giving you some ground rules.

In practice, you can do what ever you want. I mean, a device can skip IOT all together and do direct API calls using username and password (strong or not).
You would be able to log in, get some kind of token and use it to call the other APIs, but it's not really recommended.

IOT was created specifically for devices, and so the security it uses differs strongly from human login. This is because humans have a hard time remembering strong passwords, while machines do not.

So what is the best practice?

1. [IOT certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/device-certs-create.html). Each IOT device or thing can have one or more certificates that hold a policy that "says" what the device can and can't do.
2. [STS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/welcome.html). Use a human login (or AWS access key & secret key pair) to do an STS call to get temporary credentials. Pass these credentials to the device and use them to log in to IOT.

Once connected to IOT via STS or Certificate, communicate via [MQTT pub-sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/mqtt.html) topics to get and send messages between the device and the backend.

I hope this puts you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi,

Looks like you managed to get my question !
I will look a bit more into STS before accepting this answer, just to be sure, but for what I've read so far, it seems to be the right direction.

Comment: I'm facing a similar scenario here. In my opinion, in addition of what @Itamar Kerbel is saying, a huge consideration starting from what I learned from the official documentation of AWS IoT, you cannot use MQTT protocol from a browser (you can, but that isn't what the SDK is intended for) in case you need web application. You can only publish a message to an endpoint because there is no a Subscribe method listed in the docs as you can see here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_iotdata_Publish.html. There is no a Subscribe method listed.